# CSS grid auto-sizing not working when using span properties

Tags: css, css-grid

Say I have 3 blocks. Each block could have content spanning the full width of the website, or less. For example let's say block one has content that fills up the full width. The 2nd and 3rd blocks only have content that fill up less than a 1/3. How would I set up a grid that would: 1) respect the amount of content in the first block, and then allow the 2nd and third block to be side by side?

This is the farthest I've gotten: [codepen.io/anoblet/pen/VyyWzm](https://codepen.io/anoblet/pen/VyyWzm)

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Watch how the columns wrap when needed. Now what I'm running into is that if I put a span 2 on any of the columns, it looks just like I would want it. Though when I resize it, it works at any number of columns except one column. When I resize it down to 1 column, something strange happens. See here: [codepen.io/anoblet/pen/GyyEOv](https://codepen.io/anoblet/pen/GyyEOv)

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="grid-column: span 2">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Offhand it doesn't sound as though you want CSS-Grid at all. Flexbox might be a better solution.

Comment: I have a setup already that uses flexbox, though I have to replicate the table syntax in order to have different areas use a different amount of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by setting grid-column-end to -1. When trying to use grid-column: 1 / span 2, the ability to wrap columns is no longer there.